# Magento 2.3.0 setup:upgrade error unexpected '?'

Tags: magento-2.3

wamp: php7.1.9  apache2.4.23  mysql5.7.19
after install magento2.3.0,when I run php bin/magento setup:upgrade

I got bellow error:

### Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in D:\wamp64\www\eme\vendor\magento\framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write.php on line 35

Answer (score 0):

if you are using your own hosting ,such as vps ,then you need to upgrade your php to php7.2
if you are using a hosting you bought ,ask them ,then they will tell you to

execute

```
/usr/local/bin/php72 bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

instead of

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use 'php72' instead the 'php' and there would be no issues.

[image: php72]